# How to git-merge two diverged branches side-by-side into one branch?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, git-merge

I have two git branches which diverged from a common commit, say branch `A` and branch `B`:

```
      -- a -- a' -- a'' (branch A)
    /
-- o -- b -- b' -- b'' (branch B)
```

Both commits `a''` and `b''` contain a lot of similar files which are now used for different applications though. I want to keep both file structures in `a''` and `b''`.

Now, I would like to merge the two by adding the contents of `B` to `A` into a subdirectory.

A sample situation would be `script.py` in commit `o` which contains `print ('original')`. In branch `A`, the file gets changed to `print ('some feature A')` throughout a series of commits; while in branch `B`, the file gets changed to `print ('another feature B')` also throughout some commits.

How would I now end up in a branch where I have the files

```
script.py   (from A)
B/script.py   (from B)
```

with `print ('some feature A')` and `print ('another feature B')` as contents, respectively?

Note: I want to keep the incremental histories for both the A version of `script.py` and the B version `B/script.py` case to be able to `git blame` either file.

Comment: It is quit hard to understand what your case is, and what you want to achieve. Is it correct that you want to merge `B` onto `A` but keep `B` untouched? If so I would suggest create a new branch from `B`, then checkout `A` and merge it with `C`. `B` is still at the commit it were.

Comment: @sp1nakr this would work in terms of the existing files/contents in HEAD afterwards -- however I would lose the history of `A` from the commit onwards where `A` and `B` diverged...

Comment: something along these lines but starting from the same original commit instead of two separate repositories:
https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `git subtree`. In particular, this command will do exactly what you describe.

```
git subtree --prefix=B B
```

Assuming you run this command in branch `A`, it will create a subdirectory `B` with the whole codebase existing in branch `B`. History will be preserved and prefixed and the graph will look like this (`m` for merge commit).

```
-- o -- a -- a' -- a'' -- m (branch A)
    \                    /
      - b -- b' -- b'' -   (branch B)
```